# PHP $_POST value split into two attributes table

Tags: php, mysql

So I am wondering if this operation is possible in Php.
I'am simply making injection into my database using php language.

So here's the form (really simple):

```
<form action="Form2.php" method="post" id="">
<div id="Formulaire1">
<div id="Titre">
  <div class="Id">  Identifiant </div>
  <div class="Ch">  Code Horaire </div>
  <div class="Date">    Date </div>
  <div class="PlH"> Plage Horaire</div>
</div>
<div id="Box">
<input type="text" name="Identifiant"id="Identifiant" ></input>

<select name="CodeHoraire" id='CodeHoraire'>
    <option value="V1">V1</option>
    <option value="V2">V2</option>
    <option value="V3">V3</option>
    <option value="V5">V5</option>
    <option value="V6">V6</option>
    <option value="ST">ST</option>
</select>

<input type="date" max="2020-01-01" min="2010-01-01" name="the_date" id="the_date">
</input>

<select name="PlageHoraire" id="PlageHoraire">
    <option value="V1">De 18h00 à 24h00</option>
    <option value="V2">De 00h00 à 07h00</option>
</select>
(....there are 4 more inputs )
</div>
<input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Envoyer" />
</form>
```

So I've got a Table named "Formulaire" in which are presents 10 Attributes:

```
IF(isset($_POST['UnitList'])
    AND isset($_POST['Catsoin'])
    AND isset($_POST['Soin'])
    AND isset($_POST['Duree']))
{ 
header('Location: Redirection.php');

    mysqli_query($connexion,"Insert into formulaire
    (
        Form_ID,
        identifiant,
        Ch,
        Date,
        Unite,
        Catsoin,
        Soin,
        Duree,
        Debutsoin,
        Finsoin
    )
    VALUES
    (
        NULL,
         '".$_COOKIE['Identifiant']."',
         '".$_COOKIE['CodeHoraire']."',
         '".$_COOKIE['the_date']."',
         '".$_POST['UnitList']."',
         '".$_POST['Catsoin']."',
         '".$_POST['Soin']."',
         '".$_POST['Duree']."',
         '".$_COOKIE['PlageHoraire']."',
        NULL
    )") or die(mysqli_error($connexion)) ;
    }
```

?>

My injection is working well but I've got to do something really new : the Two last Attributes of the table Debutsoin, Finsoin are indeed, in my Form,pointing to only one choosen Value :

```
<select name="PlageHoraire" id="PlageHoraire">
   <option value="V1">De 18h00 à 24h00</option>
   <option value="V2">De 00h00 à 07h00</option>
</select>
```

So When a client choose the first option value "De 18h00 à 24h00" for example, This Only ONE value has got to split into two table attributes : "18h00" into Debutsoin and "24h00" into Finsoin

I Am really not that comfortable using

```
  If($_POST['PlageHoraire']=="de 18h00 à 24h00")
  {
       Insert into tableFormulaire...
  }
```

But if you have a solution, even with the IF am all hears :)
Thank you for your concern.

Comment: Your if condition is not correct `$_POST['PlageHoraire']` will give you V1 or V2 as value. so your condition will be fail each time.

Comment: SQL injection here i come! (this is not a good thing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First explode the string into an array

```
$arPlageHoraire = explode(" ",$_POST['PlageHoraire']);
```

And then do your insert query:

```
mysqli_query($connexion,"Insert into `formulaire`
(
    `Form_ID`,
    `identifiant`,
    `Ch`,
    `Date`,
    `Unite`,
    `Catsoin`,
    `Soin`,
    `Duree`,
    `Debutsoin`,
    `Finsoin`
)
VALUES
(
    NULL,
     '".$_COOKIE['Identifiant']."',
     '".$_COOKIE['CodeHoraire']."',
     '".$_COOKIE['the_date']."',
     '".$_POST['UnitList']."',
     '".$_POST['Catsoin']."',
     '".$_POST['Soin']."',
     '".$_POST['Duree']."',
     '".$arPlageHoraire[1]."',
     '".$arPlageHoraire[3]."'
)") or die(mysqli_error($connexion)) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it sound really good 

So to be sure to not make stupid coding error (I am New to development)
I make my variable array
But in order to give real values to each array i have to create them from scratch ? Such as that :
$arPlageHoraire = explode(" ",$_POST['PlageHoraire']);
If(isset($_POST['PlageHoraire']=="V1" )
{
 $arPlageHoraire[1]="18h00";
$arPlageHoraire [2]="24h00";
}

Or am I missing the point?

Comment: to make my suggestion work, you have to put your text "de 18h00 à 24h00" as the value of the option entries. by the way...take a look at the other answer

Answer (score 3):

Since you are defining the values the user can select, it would be the easiest way to just store the available values in PHP.

```
$plageHoraire = array(
  'v1' => array(
    'from' => '18h00',
    'to' => '24h00'
   ),
  'v2' => array(
    'from' => '00h00',
    'to' => '07h00'
   )
);
```

Now you can just loop over the array and create the option tags:

```
<select name="PlageHoraire" id="PlageHoraire">
<?php foreach ($plageHoraire as $id => $times) { ?>
  <option value="<?=$id?>">De <?=$times['from']?> à <?=$times['to']?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

This will give you the desired HTML output. Now, after submitting you can use the array to get the actual values from the ID:

```
$times = $plageHoraire[$_POST['PlageHoraire']];
$from = $times['from'];
$to = $times['to'];
```

You can use these values in your SQL query.

Side note: Your code is open to SQL injections. You should take a look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to make your code more secure.

Comment: Hahaha the exact solution I was just writing! Damned be my slow fingers on a monday morning...

Comment: Really great Indeed !
And as you tell me , I'll try to make it more secure

Thank you to all you guys for helping :)